# download json file instead of console.log-ging it in $.getJson()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there a way I can download a json file instead of getting with jQuery's `$.getJSON()` and logging the callback function's argument, which is the json?

I don't want to manually type it from the console.log because it is long. Is there a way I can print it perhaps, and not formatted, so I can copy - paste it into a .json file?

I can't just go to the URL as I'm passing some json to the url as `$.getJSON()`'s second argument to access the response json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using

```
JSON.stringify(response);
```

There are also many websites and plugins that will let you make POST requests from your browser such as hurl.it or Postman (Chrome app).

Comment: Thank you. I completely forgot I could do that.